# Python how to assign values to a certain row of a matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, append

In Python,

I created a 10 x 20 zero-matrix, called X:
X = numpy.zeros((10, 20))

I have another 50 x 20 matrix called A.

I want to let the 4th row of matrix X take the value of the 47th row of matrix A.

How can I write this in Python?

Note: if X is a list, then I could just write X.append ()   However, here X is not a list...then how can I do this?

Or, if I just have a list that contains 20 numbers, how can I let the 4th row of matrix X equal to that list of 20 numbers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer this. So the correct syntax for selecting an entire row in numpy is

```
M[row_number, :]
```

The : part just selects the entire row in a shorthand way.

There is also a possibility of letting it go from some index to the end by using m:, where m is some known index.

If you want to go between to known indices, then we will use

```
M[row_number, m:n]
```

where m < n.

You can equate the rows/columns of a 2D-array only if they are of the same dimension.

I won't give you the exact piece of code that you'll need, but hopefully now you can figure it out using the above piece of code.

I will also suggest playing around with all kinds of matrices, and their operations like replacing some elements, columns, and rows, as well as playing with matrix multiplication until you get the hang of it.

Some useful, commands include

```
numpy.random.rand(m, n)   # will create a matrix of dimension m x n with pseudo-random numbers between 0 and 1

numpy.random.rand(m, n)   # will create a matrix of dimension m x n with pseudo-random numbers between -1 and 1

numpy.eye(m)    # will create a m x m identity matrix.

numpy.ones((m, n))
```

And make sure to read through the docs.

Good luck! And let your Python journey be a fun one. :)

Comment: Hi Alexey, thank you! Yes I know how to specify the row and column in a matrix. But my question is I do not know how to append value from one matrix to another. For example, in the case I wrote in the question, to create X matrix, I just let X=numpy.zeros((10,20)) Matrix A is given, and it has the same number of column as X, because the dimension of A is 50 x 20. But how can I let X[4, :] equal to A[47, :] ? It's not X[4, :] = A[47, :], isn't it? Thank you!

Comment: Yup, `X[4, :] = A[47, :]` should work fine. Just give it a try.